# Windows.open append the url to my current page url

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Uder my app ; i m costomising an url to open itin a new window :

```
myURL = `http://www.google.fr/BB/196?ACTIVITYTEAM=2632&ALLIANCE=FSMG2212&ACTIVITY=VENDEUR/`
```

weh using

`window.open(myURL)` ; it doesn't open me that yurl , but i's opening this one :

```
https://www.google.fr/?http://www.google.fr/BB/196?ACTIVITYTEAM=2632&ALLIANCE=FSMG2212&ACTIVITY=VENDEUR/
```

as you can see it inject google one extra time in the begining , i want to evitate this

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: I'd say either your browser is redirecting you from the original URL to the new URL or you're missing relevant details in this post. To check on the former, check your developer tools network tab and check the option to persist logs and see if you see first a request to the original URL and then a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why is this a problem, your pop up is showing an error?

Anyway, I think you could try this:

```
var w1 = window.open();
w1.location.href='http://www.google.fr/BB/196?ACTIVITYTEAM=2632&ALLIANCE=FSMG2212&ACTIVITY=VENDEUR/';
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: still do the same , that opens : https://www.google.fr/?https://www.google.fr/BB/196?ACTIVITYTEAM=2632&ALLIANCE=FSMG2212&ACTIVITY=VENDEUR

Comment: Ok, but it is a problem? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: No , there is no errors

Comment: So... your code is right, nothing going wrong. This is a google search pattern.